# Android : Default audio recording

Tags: android, audio, local-storage, audio-recording, android-sdcard

I am trying to record audio with the following code.

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
    System.out.println("Inside Audio recording");
    File storageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/filetoupload/");
    if (!storageDir.exists()) {
        storageDir.mkdirs();
    }
    try {
            System.out.println("Inside Audio recording try block");
            imageToStore = new File(storageDir,"" + "audio.3gp");
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.Audio.Media.RECORD_SOUND_ACTION);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,Uri.fromFile(imageToStore));
            System.out.println("Inside Audio recording path"+ imageToStore);
            startActivityForResult(intent,CAPTURE_AUDIO);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

}
}
```

It will open default android recording player and let me record audio file.

So basically it will start default audio recording and should create folder name **filetoupload** inside SD-card and should store it is as a name **audio.3gp** but it is not doing same. It is storing recording inside default recording folder in device or with some other name like **recording-10555454545.3gp**

So how can i store this audio inside SD-card particular folder and with **audio.3gp** name please help.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem, have you managed to find a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            if (requestCode == RQS_RECORDING) {
                try {

                    AssetFileDescriptor videoAsset = getContentResolver()
                            .openAssetFileDescriptor(data.getData(), "r");
                    FileInputStream fis;

                    fis = videoAsset.createInputStream();

                    File root = new File(Environment
            .getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Foldername/", "AUDIO"); // you
                    if (!root.exists()) {

                        root.mkdirs();
                    }
                    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")
                            .format(new Date());
                    File file;
                    file = new File(root.getPath() + "/" + "AUD_" + timeStamp
                            + ".mp3");
                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);

                    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                    int len;
                    while ((len = fis.read(buf)) > 0) {
                        fos.write(buf, 0, len);
                    }
                    fis.close();
                    fos.close();
                Uri fileuri = Uri.fromFile(file);
                        System.out.println("you Audio path"+fileuri.getpath)


                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }


}
```

Comment: This does not seem to be an answer to the question asked.

Comment: @Palak, can you explain in brief. Because this code also contain some file operation which is not required. So what should i change with this piece of code.

Comment: @Palak, I was knowing only that this answer is not gonna work then also i tried and same problem still i am facing.

Comment: The result is passed in onActivityResult as the intent:
onActivityResult  (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
To turn that Intent data into a file that I can read, I make it into an
AssetFileDescriptor with this line:
AssetFileDescriptor videoAsset=getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(data.getData(), "r"); Once you have the AssetFileDescriptor, you can create an inputstream and
 read the file or an outputstream to write the file to ur desire place.

Comment: Can You write your error which you are facing because this is working fine for me in audio as well as video recording.